# Initialising an array of two tuples fails

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple function that returns an array of tuples

```
func findNodeNeighbors(node: Node) -> [(node: Node, distance: Double)] {
    var neighbors = [(node: Node, distance: Double)]()
    var nodeLinks = linksWith(node)
    for link in nodeLinks {
        neighbors.append((node: link.otherNodeLinkedWith(node), distance: link.length))
    }
    return neighbors
}
```

But this turns out is an error `Invalid use of () to call a clue of non-function type` on the first line of the function body.

If instead I declare the type for `neighbors` explicitly, everything is fine.

```
var neighbors: [(node: Node, distance: Double)] = []
```

How come?

I've read that it is preferred to declare arrays by initialising them and allowing for implicit type inference.

Comment: Does the `append((..., ...))` work for you? It doesn't for me and Apple lists it as a known bug.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `append()` works in this instance. I checked the contents of the array and it has the members I put there. @StevenVanImpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty certain this is a bug in Swift's parser, specifically to do with the `[Type]` sugar in combination with named tuples.

`var neighbors = Array<(node: Node, distance: Double)>()` (which should be identical to `[(node: Node, distance: Double)]()`) works fine.

edit: looks like the dictionary equivalent has the same problem

Works fine:

```
var d = Dictionary<Int,(x: Int, y: Int)>()
```

Busted:

```
var d = [Int:(x: Int, y: Int)]()
```

Comment: I feared it was that! Can't wait for that WWDC to happen any quicker... Because the current state of the Swift parser is still so far behind what Objc has.

Comment: mo' language features, mo' problems

Answer (score 2):

> what if I want an empty array as the initial value?

I am not 100% certain - but I think that another way you can quickly get around this issue currently is by declaring the tuple using a `typealias`.

Eg:

```
typealias Test = (Node, Double)

func findNodeNeighbors(node: Node) -> [Test] {
    var neighbors = [Test]()
    //etc
}
```

Comment: It does seem quite elegant (not perfect, but...) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise the array using default values:

```
var neighbors = [(node: node, distance: 0.0)]
```

Comment: what if I want an empty array as the initial value?

Comment: well, then the @Airspeed answer is the best way to go

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the effort though :)